# Moment check if date difference is greater than X months

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

So while I use the following code to check if the difference between 2 dates is X days

```
var selectedDate = moment(value, 'MM/DD/YYYY');
var today = moment();
today.diff(selectedDate, 'days');
```

I want to check if the difference between the selected date and the current dates is beyond X month (e.g. say 14 months), then I want to alert some error.

Is there an easy way to do that using moment.js ? I want that leap years and all are also considered automatically.

Comment: Just a note momentjs is now considered legacy and will not be receiving updates. https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `today.diff(selectedDate, 'months');`.

[Documentation](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/04-displaying/07-difference/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var selectedDate = moment("2020-04-21").format('YYYYMMDD');
var newdDate = moment("2020-01-22").format('YYYYMMDD');
var today = moment();

var difference = today.diff(selectedDate, 'months');
console.log('Difference', difference);

var diff = today.diff(newdDate, 'months');
console.log('New Date Difference', diff);

var floatingDiff = today.diff(selectedDate, 'months', true);
console.log('Floating', floatingDiff);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks...seems like when there is exact 15 months diff e.g. for say 22 Jan 2020, the logic might not work properly...

Comment: @testndtv You can rely on the script without the third parameter 'true'. Its will always give the rounded month difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `moment().diff()` to calculated diff b/w today & selected date or pass new date to moment if you want difference between any other date.

```
 import moment from "moment";
    const selectedDate = "2020-04-27";
    const date_temp = moment().diff(selectedDate, 'months');
    console.log(date_temp);
```